# Incorrect tag usage on company profile?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Usually when I see Job listings in the "Looking for a Job?" ad space, I see relevant tags.

This time I noticed two tags being used for a job listing which seemed to be... odd:

[image]

Maybe [TripAdvisor](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/96176/senior-software-engineer-android-team-tripadvisor) is having some serious class issues, but it seems a bit extreme to have a job specializing in [classnotfoundexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classnotfoundexception) and [noclassdeffounderror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/noclassdeffounderror).

Perhaps this was not done intentionally, or perhaps it was?

I don't know of a way to check.

Comment: Well if so they're looking for this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1046407/marcelo

Comment: "So you applied for the Classnotfoundexception specialist job. What classes have you taken?"  "You kidding me? None, of course." Or perhaps SO threw an exception when the ad was posted :)

Comment: It's still there ! Job was posted 2 weeks before and nobody noticed it. Lol  +1

Comment: Those tags were chosen by the same person who thought the android tag is irrelevant there...

Comment: @fabian WT* ! this company want android developer with no android knowledge !

Comment: @albertjan: And it looks like this might be the guy who's hiring... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn